# Distance between value function of deterministic and stochastic control problems

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, global-optimization

Suppose that one wants to control a diffusion process
$$
dX_t^u = \mu(X_t^u,u)dt + \sigma dW_t; \qquad X_0^u=x
$$
in order to optimize a stochastic control problem with value function
$$
V_T(u)=\mathbb{E}[f(X^u_T) + \int_0^T g(X_t^u)dt].
$$
Where $f,g$ are bounded smooth functions and $u$ is an admissible control.

Now suppose that one wants to optimize the deterministic control problem:
$$
\partial_t x_t^u = \mu(x_t^u,u)dt ; \qquad X_0^u=x
$$
with value function
$$
v_T(u)=f(X^u_T) + \int_0^T g(X_t^u)dt.
$$

For small $\epsilon$, when can one guarantee that the optimal policies of both problems are "close" (in expectation or some other appropriate sense)?

Comment: See this: https://www.icts.res.in/sites/default/files/ldt2017-2017-08-17-Vivek-S-Borkar.pdf

Comment: On page 18, it says "Under suitable technical conditions" where could I find those?

Comment: Maybe start here: http://www.princeton.edu/~moll/viscosity_slides.pdf